# How to customize Angular material design input field in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working in an angular 5 application ,Here I am using Angular Material Design for UI .

Now I want to design a input filed as like in the image

[image]

I don't know how to add the "Change" label inside he input field .

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stacb4-5oaagd?file=app%2Fsnack-bar-overview-example.html

app.component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-12">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="email" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use like this,

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-12">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input #inp matInput placeholder="email" required>
   <span matSuffix class="lbl" (click)="inp.value = ''">change</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in `style.css`

```
.lbl {
   color: #1787dc;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stacb4-z67mrq?file=styles.scss) demo

Answer (score 2):

use `matSuffix` for this

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-12">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="email" required>
  <button matSuffix (click)="getData()">Change</button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

**try This if you need something like this**

[image]

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-12">
    <mat-label matSuffix >Enter your email</mat-label>
  <a matSuffix > change ? </a>
    <input matInput placeholder="email" required>
</mat-form-field>
```